# why is laravel eager loading constraint not working?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have this as the basic of what i want to do but the constraint is not applying

```
$this['subs'] = Cat::with([
    'children' => function($query) {
        $query -> where('parent_id', 0);
    }
]) -> get();
```

Comment: The query seems good. As I understand, you have a `Cat` with the relationship `children`and the children has the field `parent_id`. And what you want is: Give me **all the cats** and **load** the cat's children with a `parent_id` of `0`. Is that right?

Comment: Actually give me all children by slug of parent_id=0 when clicked. That is actually what i am gunning for.

Comment: So... if I understand you correctly, what you want is : `$this['subs'] = Children::where('parent_id', 0)->get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the one you are looking for, is `whereHas` , like this:

```php
$this['subs'] = Cat::whereHas('children', function ($query) {
                  $query->where('parent_id',0);
               })->get();
```

putting a query in `with` just scopes the relationships it queries, not the record set `cat` itself.

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work. $this['subs'] = Cat::whereHas('parent', function ($query) {
                  $query->where('slug',$slug);
               })->get(); to display all children of the parent linked by slug

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a cat with id = 0?

Try:

```
Cat::with('children')->find(0)
```

Supposing you have a cat with id = 0; this will return the cat with id = 0 and its children if has any.

Or:

```
Cat::has('children')->get()
```

This will return all the cats that have children.

Or:

```
Cat::with('children')->get()
```

This will return all cats and its children if has any

Answer (score 0):

you are using `October CMS` so you can just use `traits nested-tree`

docs : https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#nested-tree

```php
class Cat extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\NestedTree;
}
```

Now

```php
$model = Cat::where('slug', $param_slug)->first();
```

and then

```php
$model->getEagerRoot(); // Returns a list of all root nodes, with ->children eager loaded.
// OR
$model->getEagerChildren(); // Returns direct child nodes, with ->children eager loaded.
```

You can have `ton of options`

> https://github.com/octobercms/library/blob/master/src/Database/Traits/NestedTree.php

```php
/* General access methods:
 *
 *   $model->getRoot(); // Returns the highest parent of a node.
 *   $model->getRootList(); // Returns an indented array of key and value columns from root.
 *   $model->getParent(); // The direct parent node.
 *   $model->getParents(); // Returns all parents up the tree.
 *   $model->getParentsAndSelf(); // Returns all parents up the tree and self.
 *   $model->getChildren(); // Set of all direct child nodes.
 *   $model->getSiblings(); // Return all siblings (parent's children).
 *   $model->getSiblingsAndSelf(); // Return all siblings and self.
 *   $model->getLeaves(); // Returns all final nodes without children.
 *   $model->getDepth(); // Returns the depth of a current node.
 *   $model->getChildCount(); // Returns number of all children.
 *
 * Query builder methods:
 *
 *   $query->withoutNode(); // Filters a specific node from the results.
 *   $query->withoutSelf(); // Filters current node from the results.
 *   $query->withoutRoot(); // Filters root from the results.
 *   $query->children(); // Filters as direct children down the tree.
 *   $query->allChildren(); // Filters as all children down the tree.
 *   $query->parent(); // Filters as direct parent up the tree.
 *   $query->parents(); // Filters as all parents up the tree.
 *   $query->siblings(); // Filters as all siblings (parent's children).
 *   $query->leaves(); // Filters as all final nodes without children.
 *   $query->getNested(); // Returns an eager loaded collection of results.
 *   $query->listsNested(); // Returns an indented array of key and value columns.
 *
 * Flat result access methods:
 *
 *   $model->getAll(); // Returns everything in correct order.
 *   $model->getAllRoot(); // Returns all root nodes.
 *   $model->getAllChildren(); // Returns all children down the tree.
 *   $model->getAllChildrenAndSelf(); // Returns all children and self.
 *
 * Eager loaded access methods:
 *
 *   $model->getEagerRoot(); // Returns a list of all root nodes, with ->children eager loaded.
 *   $model->getEagerChildren(); // Returns direct child nodes, with ->children eager loaded.
 *
 */
```

please check it out its really fast and convenient way for parent and child relations.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried it with the following $this['subs'] = Cat::where('slug', $this->param_slug)->first();

$this['subs']->getEagerChildren(); 
my foreach is this  {% for subs in subs %}
        <li>
               
                {{ subs.cat_title }}
               
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="no-data">{{ noRecordsMessage }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
     but is turns up empty after i click on main cat. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: your loop is `{% for subs in subs %}` can you use different variable there `{% for items in subs %}`

Comment: Ok. Just one last thing. Using octobercms nestedtree, do i still need to define the parent, children relationship in the model?

Comment: no you don't need to define them it will defined automatically check : https://github.com/octobercms/library/blob/master/src/Database/Traits/NestedTree.php#L90
it defines `children` and `parent` when you use this trait

Comment: maybe i am doing it wrong after this $model = Cat::where('slug', $param_slug)->first(); followed by $model->getEagerChildren(); i get this error Method getEagerChildrenf does not exist.

Comment: can you share your modal code and code for getting children

Comment: `$this['subs'] = Cat::where('slug', $this->param('slug'))->first();` and then `$this['subs'] = ->getEagerChildren();` and then foreach `{% if subs %}

<ul class="record-list">
 
    {% for subs in subs %}
        <li>
               
               {{ subs.cat_title }}
               
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="no-data">{{ noRecordsMessage }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    
    
    </ul>
    {% endif%} ` i also tried replacing `first` with `get`.

Comment: I think my problem is coming from the slug. when i remove the slug conditional, it renders with children